# Trying to do webscraping of imdb site , but am getting syntax error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried from another site am getting the required output, but it is showing error here.

```py
import requests import pandas as pd from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request=requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/what-to-watch/fan-favorites/?ref_=hm_fanfav_sm')
#print(request) soup=BeautifulSoup(request.content,'html.parser')
#print(soup) names=soup.find_all('span',data-testid='title') print(names)
```

After running this, I'm getting a syntax error:

```py
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant
"=="?
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's taking `data-testid` to be `data - testid`, like two variables being subtracted. maybe try using this:

```py
soup.findAll("span",attrs={"data-testid"="title"})
```